# Gaussian Process Regression with null values

Tags: gaussian-process

I hope i am posting this to the right place...

I am using sklearn's GPR to model some hyper-parameter optimization. Because of the nested nature of the parameter space i am working with (ex. if parameter A is false, parameter B then may not be an active param) i need to find a way for the gpr to ignore features in the sample.

I've tried simply using null for these values but the GPR fit() method expects a non-null array.

I want to fit a gaussian process using samples that contain null feature every now and then.